# XACML policies - Using regex for attribute values inside conditions

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I want to use regex for the attribute values to match the resource names. For example, http://localhost.*/private/team, so that the following values matches

http://localhost:8080/private/team, 
http://localhost:8080/abcd/private/team

I have the following policy

```
    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="InStorePolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
       <Target>
          <AnyOf>
             <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">access</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </Match>
             </AllOf>
          </AnyOf>
       </Target>
       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_for_employee">
          <Target>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                           <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">employee</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
          </Target>
          <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/support</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/team</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
       </Rule>
       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_for_manager">
          <Target>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                           <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
          </Target>
          <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/business</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/leadership</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
       </Rule>
       <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule_deny_all"/>
    </Policy>
```

The resources are within the condition tag. I tried and couldn't add the string-regex function inside the condition. is it possible for me to add regex functions inside string-bag ? Or do I have to move it to target ? How can I achieve this ?

Regards,
Albie Morken

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you could simply use one of the following XACML functions:

- stringContains (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains)
- stringEndsWith (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-ends-with)

### Edit

These two functions work on atomic values e.g. `"a"`, or `"b"`. By default, attributes in XACML are bags. This means that role is a bag of values (could be 0, 1, or more values - a bag nonetheless). This means that if you want to use stringContains() on a bag, you need to either use stringOneAndOnly first to convert the bag into a single value or you need to use a higher-order function.

#### stringOneAndOnly

Try the following for instance (using ALFA notation)

```
// The result SHALL be true if the second string contains the first string, and false otherwise.
stringContains("manager", stringOneAndOnly(role))
```

#### Higher-order functions

Alternatively you can use `AnyOf` or `AnyOfAny` applied to `stringContains()`.

Comment: But how can I use it with string-bag ? I need something like the one below    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-ends-with">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost.*/private/support</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost.*/private/team</AttributeValue>
            </Apply>
            Is there any other way to check stringendswith from a list ?